# Close Submenus and Change Focus on Menu Click in Recursive React Menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have implemented a recursive menu in React using Material-UI, where each menu item can have submenus. I'm trying to achieve the following functionalities:

1.When clicking on the menu, regardless of the current focus or open submenus, I want to close all other submenus and focus only on the clicked menu.

2.Additionally, I want to close all open submenus and menu if I click outside the recursive menu of menus.

this my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';

const RecursiveMenu = ({ menuItems }) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        {Object.values(menuItems)
          .filter((menuItem) => menuItem.showing !== false)
          .map((menuItem) => (
            <RecursiveMenuItem key={menuItem.id} menuItem={menuItem} />
          ))}
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

const RecursiveMenuItem = ({ menuItem }) => {
  const [subMenuAnchorEl, setSubMenuAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [showingState, setShowingState] = useState(menuItem.showing);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    if (menuItem.options) {
      setSubMenuAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    } else {
      // Toggle between 0, 1, and 2 for checked, indeterminate, and unchecked
      setShowingState((prevState) => (prevState + 1) % 3);
    }
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setSubMenuAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MenuItem style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }} onClick={handleClick}>
        <span>{menuItem.name}</span>
        {!menuItem.options && (
          <Checkbox
            checked={showingState === 0}
            indeterminate={showingState === 1}
            onChange={handleClick}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'indeterminate-checkbox' }}
          />
        )}
      </MenuItem>
      {menuItem.options && (
        <Menu
          anchorEl={subMenuAnchorEl}
          open={Boolean(subMenuAnchorEl)}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          {Object.values(menuItem.options)
            .filter((subMenuItem) => subMenuItem.showing !== false)
            .map((subMenuItem) => (
              <RecursiveMenuItem key={subMenuItem.id} menuItem={subMenuItem} />
            ))}
        </Menu>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const menuItems = {
    A: { id: "A", name: "A", enabled: false, showing: 0 },
    B: { id: "B", name: "B", enabled: false, showing: 2 },
    C: {
      id: "c",
      name: "C",
      options: {
        C1: { id: "C1", name: "C1", enabled: false, showing: 1 },
        C2: {
          id: "C2", name: "C2", options:
          {
            C21: { id: "C21", name: "C2.1", enabled: false, showing: 0 },
            C22: { id: "C22", name: "C2.2", enabled: false, showing: 2 },
          }
        },
      },
    },
    Shaun: { id: "D", name: "D", enabled: false, showing: 2 },
  };

  return <RecursiveMenu menuItems={menuItems} />;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
...
const RecursiveMenu = ({ menuItems }) => {
  ...

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    ...
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        {Object.values(menuItems)
          .filter((menuItem) => menuItem.showing !== false)
          .map((menuItem) => (
            <RecursiveMenuItem key={menuItem.id} menuItem={menuItem} onClick={handleClose} />
          ))}
      </Menu>
      ...
  );
};

const RecursiveMenuItem = ({ menuItem, onClick }) => {
  ...

  const handleClose = () => {
    setSubMenuAnchorEl(null);
    onClick();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MenuItem style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }} onClick={handleClick}>
        <span>{menuItem.name}</span>
        {!menuItem.options && (
          <Checkbox
            checked={showingState === 0}
            indeterminate={showingState === 1}
            onChange={handleClick}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'indeterminate-checkbox' }}
          />
        )}
      </MenuItem>
      {menuItem.options && (
        <Menu
          anchorEl={subMenuAnchorEl}
          open={Boolean(subMenuAnchorEl)}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          {Object.values(menuItem.options)
            .filter((subMenuItem) => subMenuItem.showing !== false)
            .map((subMenuItem) => (
              <RecursiveMenuItem key={subMenuItem.id} menuItem={subMenuItem} onClick={handleClose} />
            ))}
        </Menu>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```